# Asynchronous jsf managed bean methode call and update div-elemen in xhtml

Tags: jsf

How to implement asynchronous managed bean method call and then update div element?

Using jsf 2.2 with primefaces 6 and tomcat8

thanks for your help

Comment: @Balus, the post was 6 years ago. Is that today the same way to solve the problem?

Comment: Answer is last updated January 2017 and even talks about JSF 2.3 which is newer than yours.